# Find the Derivative and simplify (write w/o negative exponents and factor if possible) y=cos^3(x^2+2)

Tags: calculus

I am currently practicing on an old college calculus final. Would like to know if my work is correct.

Find the derivative for f(x) = x^1/2 + (3/x^2)-2 and y=cos^3(x^2+2) . Thanks for your help.
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got one part right, but there are a few mistakes. For example, the function $\frac{3}{x^2}-2$ is equivalently written as $3x^{-2}-2$. By the power rule, the derivative would be $$(-2)3x^{-2-1} = -6x^{-3} = \frac{-6}{x^3}$$ Your derivative of $x^{1/2}$ is correct.

The derivative of $\cos^3(x^3+2)$ is wrong for a few reasons. First, you are missing one "layer" in your chain rule. Second, it is the cosine argument being raised to the $3$rd power, *not* the quantity $(x^3+2)$ inside the argument of cosine. You can think of it as $$\left[\cos(x^3+2) \right]^3 = \cos(x^3+2)\cdot \cos(x^3+2) \cdot \cos(x^3+2)$$ By the power rule, you should get $$\frac{d}{dx}\left[\cos(x^3+2) \right]^3  = 3\left[\cos(x^3+2) \right]^2 \cdot \left[\frac{d}{dx} \cos(x^3+2)\right]$$ In differentiating $\frac{d}{dx}\cos(x^3+2)$ you should get $$-\sin(x^3+2) \cdot \left[\frac{d}{dx}(x^3+2)\right] = -\sin(x^3+2)\cdot 3x^2$$ So all together, $$\frac{d}{dx}\left[\cos(x^3+2) \right]^3 = -9x^2\left[\cos(x^3+2) \right]^2\sin(x^3+2)$$

Comment: You mean the chain rule not the power, right? Where did you get the nine from?

Comment: Well, both. The power rule puts the "$3$" in front of the $\cos^2(x^3+2)$ term. The chain rule tells you that you still need to multiply by $\frac{d}{dx}\cos(x^3+2)$. The $-9$ comes from $3 \cdot -3$

Comment: Honestly, by looking at my work, how competent am I at Calculus?

Comment: Your calculus looks not too bad to me, you seem to know when and where you need to apply rules. Your algebra is what is getting you though. stuff like remembering $$x^{-2} = \frac{1}{x^2}$$ or $$\sin^2(y) = \sin(y) \cdot \sin(y)$$ instead of $\sin^2(y) = \sin(y^2)$. Calculus is just algebra and trigonometry with limits. If you are sharp with algebra and trig, your calculus will improve drastically :)

Answer (score 0):

Hint:
$$
\dfrac{d}{dx}\dfrac{1}{x^2}=\dfrac{d}{dx}x^{-2}=-2x^{-3}
$$
In the second you have an initial mistake:
$$
\dfrac{d}{dx}\cos^3(x^3+2)=\dfrac{d}{dx}\left[ \cos(x^3+2)\right]^3=3\left[ \cos(x^3+2)\right]^2\dfrac{d}{dx}\cos(x^3+2)=....
$$